# Vite not bundling properly JInja2 project

Tags: jinja2, bundle, vite, static-site-generation

I'm building a static-generated (SSG) landing page with **Vite + Jinja2**. I've made a plugin to parse the `.html` files written in Jinja2 and that works fine during development.

However during build, the javascript files included in base.html are **totally missing**. Namely it seems that Vite simply runs the Jinja2 parsing and outputs the result without running the bundling against the generated content, so I end up with something like below.

project:

```
src
 ├── base.html (includes all js)
 ├── index.html (extends base)
 └── js
     ├── main.js
     └── mail.js
```

bundle output:

```
dist
 └── index.html
```

bundled index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./js/mail.js"></script>
    ..
```

My plugin (vite.config.js):

```js
// Parse HTML files written in Jinja2 syntax
const htmlJinja2Parse = () => {
  return {
    name: 'html-transform',
    transformIndexHtml(html) {
      try {
        const modifiedHtml = execSync('python jinja2parse.py', {
          input: html,
          encoding: 'utf-8',
        });
        return modifiedHtml;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to execute the Python script:', error);
        return html; // Return the original HTML in case of an error
      }
    },
  }
}


export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  return {
    ..
    build: {
      outDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      emptyOutDir: true,
      rollupOptions: {
        input: {
          // Specify all HTML files to build
          main: "./src/index.html",
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      htmlJinja2Parse(),
    ]
  }
});
```

Any ideas why Vite skips bundling the generated content? Help much appreciated